# Correct usage of TensorFlow Transform apply_buckets

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-transform

This is on TensorFlow 1.11.0. The [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/transform/api_docs/python/tft/apply_buckets) of `tft.apply_buckets` is not very descriptive. In specific, I read: 
"bucket_boundaries: The bucket boundaries represented as a rank 2 Tensor."

I assume this has to be bucket indices and bucket boundaries?

When I try with the toy example below:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_transform as tft
import numpy as np

tf.enable_eager_execution()

x = np.array([-1,9,19, 29, 39])
xt = tf.cast(
        tf.convert_to_tensor(x),
        tf.float32
        )

boundaries = tf.cast(
                tf.transpose(
                    tf.convert_to_tensor([[0, 1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30, 40]])
                    ),
                tf.float32
                )

buckets = tft.apply_buckets(xt, boundaries)
```

I get:

`InvalidArgumentError: Expected sorted boundaries [Op:BucketizeWithInputBoundaries] name: assign_buckets`

Note that in this case `x` and `bucket_boundaries` arguments are:

```
tf.Tensor([-1.  9. 19. 29. 39.], shape=(5,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[[ 0. 10.]
 [ 1. 20.]
 [ 2. 30.]
 [ 3. 40.]], shape=(4, 2), dtype=float32)
```

So, it seems like `bucket_boundaries` is not supposed to be indices and boundaries. Does anyone know how to properly use this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some playing around, I found out that `bucket_boundaries` is supposed to be a 2 dimensional array where entries are bucket boundaries and the array is wrapped so it has two columns. See example below:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_transform as tft
import numpy as np

tf.enable_eager_execution()

x = np.array([-1,9,19, 29, 39])
xt = tf.cast(
        tf.convert_to_tensor(x),
        tf.float32
        )

boundaries = tf.cast(
                tf.transpose(
                    tf.convert_to_tensor([[0, 20, 40, 60], [10, 30, 50, 70]])
                    ),
                tf.float32
                )

buckets = tft.apply_buckets(xt, boundaries)
```

So, the expected inputs are:

```py
print (xt)
print (buckets)
print (boundaries)
```

```
tf.Tensor([-1.  9. 19. 29. 39.], shape=(5,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0 1 2 3 4], shape=(5,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(
[[ 0. 10.]
 [20. 30.]
 [40. 50.]
 [60. 70.]], shape=(4, 2), dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to add to this as this is the only result for the Google search "tft.apply_buckets" :)

The example for me did not work in the latest version of TFT. The following code did work for me.

Note that the buckets are specified as a rank 2 tensor, but with only one element in the inner dimension.

(I'm using the wrong words but hopefully my example below will clarify)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_transform as tft
import numpy as np

tf.enable_eager_execution()

xt = tf.cast(tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array([-1,9,19, 29, 39])),tf.float32)
bds = [[0],[10],[20],[30],[40]]
boundaries = tf.cast(tf.convert_to_tensor(bds),tf.float32)
buckets = tft.apply_buckets(xt, boundaries)
```

thanks for your help as this answer got me most of the way there!

The rest I found from the TFT source code:
https://github.com/tensorflow/transform/blob/deb198d59f09624984622f7249944cdd8c3b733f/tensorflow_transform/mappers.py#L1697-L1698

Answer (score 0):

I love this answer, just wanted to add some simplification as enabling eager execution, casting, and numpy aren't really needed.  Note that casting below for the float case is done by making one of the scalars a float, tensorflow standardizes on the highest fidelity data type.

The code below shows how this mapping works. The number of buckets created is the length of bucket boundaries vector + 1, or (in my opinion), more intuitively, the minimum number of commas + 2.  Plus two because negative infinity to the smallest value, and the largest value to infinity. If something is on the bucket boundary, it goes to the bucket representing bigger numbers.  What happens when the bucket boundaries aren't sorted is left as an exercise for the reader :)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_transform as tft
xt = tf.constant([-1., 9, 19, 29, 39, float('nan'), float('-inf'), float('inf')])
bucket_boundaries = tf.constant([[0], [10], [20], [30], [40]])
bucketed_floats = tft.apply_buckets(xt, bucket_boundaries)

for scalar, index in zip(xt, range(len(xt))):
    print(f"{scalar} was mapped to bucket {bucketed_floats[index]}.")
```

> -1.0 was mapped to bucket 0.
> 9.0 was mapped to bucket 1.
> 19.0 was mapped to bucket 2.
> 29.0 was mapped to bucket 3.
> 39.0 was mapped to bucket 4.
> nan was mapped to bucket 5.
> -inf was mapped to bucket 0.
> inf was mapped to bucket 5.

```
xt_int = tf.constant([-1, 9, 19, 29, 39, 41])
bucketed_ints = tft.apply_buckets(xt_int, bucket_boundaries)

for scalar, index in zip(xt_int, range(len(xt_int))):
    print(f"{scalar} was mapped to bucket {bucketed_ints[index]}.")
```

> -1 was mapped to bucket 0.
> 9 was mapped to bucket 1.
> 19 was mapped to bucket 2.
> 29 was mapped to bucket 3.
> 39 was mapped to bucket 4.
> 41 was mapped to bucket 5.

Note that there's also a function called `tft.bucketize` which appears to require a full pass over the data.  I'm not a 100% clear on the nuance between `tft.apply_buckets` and `tft.bucketize`.